# Program bash is not found in path?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I have tried many times to set up Cocos2dx in Eclipse, but haven't been able to get it to work. I am getting this error:

> bash is not found in path

I have tried all kinds of stuff available on Stackoverflow but have not found any solution that fixes this error in my system. I am using Window 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Cygwin(if not installed).Make sure you install `make` module.

Set the path of `bin` folder in environment variables like `c:/cygwin/bin`.Name it `Path` . This should work.

You can refer this [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/26574) also

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable `PATH`, and add:
`your_cygwin\bin;your_cocos2d-x\projects\your_project\proj.android;your_ndk\`

Example:
`C:\android-ndk-r9c;C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\projects\MyProject\proj.android`

Answer (score 0):

For answer to your question, go to the properties project, in the tab "C/C++ build" choose "Tool Chain Editor" and change the option  "Current builder" to -Android Builder-